# RegEx, accepting wrong string

Tags: java, regex

This is the first version of my RegEx

```
(^[0-9]?[0-9]?.[0-9]?[0-9]?$?)|(^[0-9]?[0-9]?$)
```

I want to accept only strings like **22.22** , **2.22** . **22.2**, **.2** , **22** , **empty string**, etc.

However,  it accepts 256, 2568, 25690 too and I don't know why.

Also, I have tried another version and it doesn't work too.

```
(^[0-9]{0,2}.{1}[0-9]{0,2}$)?|(^[0-9]{0,2}$)
```

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear at all.

Comment: maybe you need to escape the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX2kC8/1)

It will accept:

```
22.22
2.22
22.2
.2
22
<empty>
```

But won't match:

```
256
2568
25690
```